# Domain without a suffix not resolving internally, cannot add new PCs to domain

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns

I have an AD domain that doesn't have a suffix and am having an issue with workstations not being able to join the domain.

I'll refer to their domain as "school", they also own the public facing domain and have a "school.org". (school is an example, not their actual domain name)

In troubleshooting I found that I cannot ping/resolve the domain "school" from a domain controller or any pc, oddly enough I can ping/resolve a server or workstation in the domain by using "server1.school". The 2 AD DCs have DNS installed (all workstations point to the DCs for DNS), there is a TLD for "school" in DNS there along with A and CNAME records for "school" pointing back to the domain controllers. The other strange thing is that I can resolve "school.", notice the . at the end.

On other thing I have noticed is that I can set a hosts file on a workstation to point "school" to an IP of a DC, in doing so I get an error when joining the domain that the domain controller list could be found but none could be reached. So I did a \school\netlogon and was able to see that after providing credentials.

DCdiag /test:dns shows no errors.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank You.

Comment: In DNS can you see the SRV records registered by your DC's https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx

Comment: Yes, for both DCs. I see SRV records for gc, ldap, kpasswd, and kerbros.